# ZipFile Check for Completion

Tags: c#

Currently I'm using the following code to extract Zip files.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/" + "MySQL Data.zip", folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/Release/");
```

After it's done I'd like to extract another Zip file, so how can I check to see if the zip file has been extracted successfully?

Comment: When no exception is raised?

Comment: I guess that could work. I'm just surprised that there is no method to check for completion for ZipFile.

Comment: The docs show you what possible exceptions can be raised https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.  If your call to `ExtractToDirectory` executes with no exceptions thrown, you can assume the ZIP was extracted successfully, and it's not asynchronous, so you'll know the extraction is done on the next line that executes (if no exception was thrown).

Comment: There is no method to check for completition of an `=` operator either. If the execution goes to the next command without exception, then the `=` operator completed successfully.